# Camel-3 in OSGI no load ScheduledPollConsumerScheduler

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm use karaf features

```
<feature>camel-core</feature>
<feature>camel-quartz</feature>
```

In my maven project, pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Use Camel 2.x.y in my route

```
file://data?recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=....
```

I't work good.

Use Camel 3.0.0. Failed to create route.

```
file://data?recursive=true&scheduler=quartz&scheduler.cron=....
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load
>   org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler
>   from classpath. Make sure camel-quartz.jar is on the classpath.
>       at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollEndpoint.configureScheduledPollConsumerProperties(ScheduledPollEndpoint.java:141)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollEndpoint.configureProperties(ScheduledPollEndpoint.java:113)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:256)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:755)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:55)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:120)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:363)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:108)
>   ~[?:?]
>       ... 57 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver.resolveMandatoryClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:96)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollEndpoint.configureScheduledPollConsumerProperties(ScheduledPollEndpoint.java:138)
>   ~[?:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollEndpoint.configureProperties(ScheduledPollEndpoint.java:113)
>   ~[?:?]

Comment: How do you bootstrap Camel in OSGi? Via a blueprint xml file or something else?

Comment: And can you try to enable dynamic import on camel-base bundle, I think its dev:dynamic-import NNN where NNN is bundle number as karaf command.

Comment: I use Dynamic OSGi component. (org.osgi.service.component)
Component camel-osi-core. Example from file pom.xml
_org.osgi.service.event;resolution:=optional_

I think there is a similar line missing somewhere for the package _org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz_.

Comment: Did you manage to overcome this somehow? I'm having same problem.

Comment: And btw I'm using Camel 3.0.1

Comment: In a local project, maven-bundle-plugin. Section configuration, DynamicImport-Package. Add a line org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz;version="[3,4)"